# Simple Android test - just want to run the activity and have non-zero code coverage

Tags: android, testing, junit

I'm new to testing in Android (and in general).  I just want to generate an Emma code coverage report that is non-zero.

Here is my main project:
http://pastebin.com/PzS4mYMb

Here is my test project:
http://pastebin.com/7ZqTjF0g

What am I doing wrong - why is the code coverage zero?

I'm using the Monkey to try to generate events in the hopes that that would start the activity, but still, nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't your test method have a `@Test` annotation?

Comment: I don't know - should it?  :P

Comment: The `@Test` annotation is what marks a method as a test. I don't think it runs it otherwise.

Comment: Just added it - Eclipse offered to add JUnit 4 to the build path, is that right?

Comment: Yes, unless you're using a different test framework that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Hmm, now I get some errors when running including "Didn't find class "org.junit.Test" on path /system/framework/android.test.runner..."  is there something else I must do?

Comment: Nevermind, I took a look at this EMMA thing, and it looks like a unit testing framework isn't needed, so that's not your problem.